# How to parse an url and get query parameters in lua?

Tags: regex, url, lua

For example, below is the url `http://www.example.com/test.html?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3`,  I want to get the key1 and key2 parameters. Are there any convient methods to work it ?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/FtEMUd

Comment: You can use an existing Lua library, for instance [neturl](https://github.com/golgote/neturl).